# p4db url for displaying a range of changelist descriptions

Tags: perforce

I need to construct a p4db url which displays a range of changelist descriptions. I noticed that it's possible to display a daterange with something like:

```
http://my_p4db/changeList.cgi?FSPC=//depot/...&DATERANGE=2015/9/9:1:5:42,2015/9/9:9:32:56&ignore=GO%21
```

And, a page of changes can be displayed with:

```
http://my_p4db/changeList.cgi?STATUS=submitted&FIRSTCH=1528176&CHOFFSETDISP=100&MAXCH=100&FSPC=//depot/...
```

But, it doesn't seem like a LASTCH parameter is supported.